# Generate then read contents from a file chef

Tags: chef-infra

What I'm trying to accomplish is to generate an ssh-key and set the public key to a node attribute so I can later search on that node attribute and add it to the other servers/users authorized_keys.

My first attempt is this:

```rb
key = '/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa'

bash "generate_key" do
  user "vagrant"
  code <<-EOH
    ssh-keygen -f #{key} -t rsa -N ''
  EOH
  not_if { ::File.exists?(key) }
end

ruby_block "reload_config" do
  block do
    node.default['test'] = IO.read("#{key}.pub")
    node.save
  end
  action :create
end

node.save #because i donno?

log "#{node['test']}"
```

This fails because (i think) the ruby block is evaluated before the bash block, so there is no file to read and or the `node['test']` is evaluated at compile time so it is blank (though it doesn't work on the second converge either, when the file does exist).

I feel lost in something that seems trivial on the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented sth. very similar [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/gerrit/blob/77f05d33aefb93de670796e81c7b3322264c22a4/recipes/peer_keys.rb#L23-L42)

```rb
ruby_block "save keys to attributes" do
  only_if { public_key.to_s == "" }
  block do
    private_key = File.read(ssh_key)
    public_key = File.read(ssh_key + ".pub")
    node.set['gerrit']['peer_keys']['private'] = private_key
    node.set['gerrit']['peer_keys']['public'] = public_key
  end
end
```

I think the precedence level "default" that you use is causing the problems, but I'm unsure, what the exact problem is in your code.

Comment: Changing from default to set didnt do the trick. But using your code did, I'm trying to understand why. Is it because everything is done at converge time rather than compile time?

Comment: Not sure, have you tried to remove the `only_if` inside the `ruby_block` to see, if it still works?